# On estimation of lifetimes of quadruple star systems whose orbit decays as a consequence of gravitational waves radiation

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, orbital-motion, gravitational-waves

The orbital decay of binaries due to gravitational wave radiation is well known and studied. I want to extend this concept to quadruple star systems such as the Capella star systems. After doing a bit of work I derived a formula for determining the lifetime of such systems. My formula that I got for Binaries works and I have got precise results with very minimal error, however, the formula for quadruple star systems' lifetime doesn't work.

Here is my work:

Let the stars if different masses be represented in the $x-y$ coordinate system with the masses occupying the following points:

$m_{1}=[r_{1}cos(\psi), r_{1}sin(\psi)]$, $m_{2}=[-r_{2}cos(\psi), -r_{2}sin(\psi)]$, $m_{3}=[-r_{3}cos(\psi), r_{3}sin(\psi)]$, and $m_{4}=[r_{4}cos(\psi), -r_{4}sin(\psi)]$

Now the total radiated power can be found(by integrating the derivative of power with respect to the solid angle) as:

> $$P_{GW}= \frac{G}{5c^{5}}\left(\frac{d^{3}Q_{ij}}{dt^{3}}\frac{d^{3}Q_{ij}}{dt^{3}}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{d^{3}Q_{ij}}{dt^{3}}\frac{d^{3}Q_{ij}}{dt^{3}}\right)$$

If we assume that the two bodies making up the binary lie in the $x-y$ plane and their **orbits are circular** ($\epsilon=0$), then only non-vanishing components of quadrupole tensors are:
$$\boxed{Q_{xx}=-Q_{yy}=\frac{1}{2}(\mu)a^{2}\cos2\Omega t}$$ and 
$$\boxed{Q_{xy}=Q_{yx}=\frac{1}{2}(\mu)a^{2}\sin2\Omega t}$$
Where $\Omega$ is the orbital velocity, $\mu=\dfrac{m_{1}m_{2}m_{3}m_{4}}{m}$ is the reduced mass and where $m=m_{1}+m_{2}+m_{3}+m_{4}$

The time can be found by taking the ratio of the total energy to the luminosity, accounting for the eccentricity of the elliptical orbit.

> $$T(a_{0},e_{0})=\frac{12}{19}\frac{{\alpha_{0}}^{4}}{\beta}\frac{2e_{0}^{\frac{48}{19}}}{\frac{96}{19}}\epsilon_{F_1}$$

Where $\alpha_{0}=\frac{a(1-e^{2})}{e^{12/19}}$ ,$$\epsilon_{F_1}=F_{1}\left(\frac{24}{19};1.5;-\frac{1181}{2299};\frac{43}{19},e_{0}^{2},-\frac{121}{304}e_{0}^{2}\right)$$ is AppellF1 hypergeometric function and $$\beta=\frac{64G^{3}\mu_{1}\mu_{2}(\mu_{1}+\mu_{2})}{5c^{5}}$$

Applying the above formula to the [HD 98800](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_98800) star system which is quadruple star system made up of two sub-Binaries, $Aa,Ab$ and $Ba,Bb$ with the following data:

$m_{1}=m_{2}=0.95$ Solar mass and $m_{3}=0.75,m_{4}=0.45$ Solar mass, eccentricity, $e=0.993$ and semi-major axis, $a=38AU$. Link to Appell solution: [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/webMathematica/FunctionEvaluation.jsp?name=AppellF1&ptype=0&a=24/19&b1=1.5&b2=-1181/2299&c=43/19&z1=0.986049&z2=-0.3924734507&digits=10)

$$T\approx{361.264}Myr$$
(wiki says that its age is in the range of $2-12Myr$)

The system consists of four T Tauri stars. According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0011135v2.pdf) the temperature of the system is $4500K$ which corresponds to the temperature of the stellar class $K5$, using relations on [this wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_sequence), the lifetime can be calculated to be $0.189123Gyr$

Where am I going wrong in my formulation? Any help is deeply valued and appreciated.

**edit:**

Calculations done for the ellipse of the quadruple system by the suggestion of @DilithiumMatrix:

> [image]

Comment: The Wikipedia page says that it is $7 \pm 5\,\mathrm{Myr}$ *old*, not that its lifetime is $7 \pm 5\,\mathrm{Myr}$.  Your second link (to the solution) seems to be wrong, as well.

Comment: @tfb thanks for pointing that out! I have made an edit regarding the calculations of the lifetime made by the luminosity-mass relations. My answer still seems way off.

Comment: 1) The GW lifetime of the system will be many many orders of magnitude longer than a Hubble time.  Only compact binaries (NS or BH) are shorter than a Hubble time.  2) The "lifetime" of a quadruple system isn't well defined.  Don't you just want the first pair that coalesces?  3) To very high accuracy, the GW losses will just be the GW from each sub-binary, and then from the orbit of each sub-binary's COM about each-other.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix that was exactly my first approach to the problem. But the resulting answer I got was wayyy off. I think the problem is that although the eccentricities of the individual binaries are defined, their orbital arrangement is not known, I.e., if in a binary, the ellipses are concentric around the COM or they pass through each other like in this-https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star .

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix The other problem is that the resulting ellipses in which the binaries move around a COM of the quadruple system can have many combinations is and is not well defined, cause it is that eccentricity that matters. So the actual Hubble data is required for precise simulations of the quadruple system.

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason why that approximation wouldn't work, if the input parameters are at all reasonable... I think there might be a different problem.  Can you include the parameters of the system  (i.e. semi-major axes for each pair)?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix I have done that calc, considering the ellipse of the quadruple system. Please checkout the edit.

Comment: Yeah, $10^{24}$ yrs sounds very believable.  As suggested by my comment (1) above.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix do you know any site where I can crosscheck if I'm right. Anyplace or any book where data regarding the decay time of star systems is available?